# Mysql failure to Table connection

Tags: php, mysql

I want to get a connection to my MySQL Database Table.
But I get the whole time a failure.

The Code for the Table looks like this:

```
 $sql_befehl = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Beitrag (
      ID        INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
      Name      VARCHAR(30),
      eMail     VARCHAR(70),
      HP        VARCHAR(70),
      IP        VARCHAR(16),
      Zeit      INT(11),
      Beitrag   TEXT,
      Kommentar TEXT
    )";

if (mysql_query($sql_befehl)) {
      echo "Success<br>" ;  
    } else {
      echo "Failure: <br>" ;
    }
```

Hope you can help me.

Comment: What does `echo mysql_error()` show when you get the failure?

Comment: You probably do not have rights to create tables with that MySQL user.

Comment: Is that the code to create the table or the code that is failing for you?

Comment: Never output a fixed (USELESS) error message. Have the DB **TELL** you why it failed: `mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());`

Answer (score 0):

If you are creating a connection using a PDO object, you can use:

`echo $dbc->getAttribute(PDO::ATTR_CONNECTION_STATUS) . "\n";`

**Example:**

```
define('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1');
define('DB_NAME', 'db_name');
define('DB_USER', 'db_user');
define('DB_PASS', 'db_pass); 

$dbc = new PDO('mysql:host='. DB_HOST .';dbname='. DB_NAME, DB_USER, DB_PASS);

echo $dbc->getAttribute(PDO::ATTR_CONNECTION_STATUS) . "\n";

$drop_table = "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Beitrag";

$dbc->exec($drop_table);

$create_table = 'CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Beitrag (
  ID        INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  Name      VARCHAR(30),
  eMail     VARCHAR(70),
  HP        VARCHAR(70),
  IP        VARCHAR(16),
  Zeit      INT(11),
  Beitrag   TEXT,
  Kommentar TEXT
)';

$dbc->exec($create_table);
```